# kafka-python KafkaProducer App failing (exiting with code 1) due to NameError: name 'json' is not defined

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am following this tutorial: https://florimond.dev/blog/articles/2018/09/building-a-streaming-fraud-detection-system-with-kafka-and-python/

The script to create the Producer App is failing, exiting with code 1, due to a NameError: name 'json' is not defined.

Here is the full output:

> > xxxx@xxxx:~/xxxx/fraud_detection$ docker-compose up WARNING: Found orphan containers (fraud_detection_zookeeper_1,
> > fraud_detection_broker_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed
> > this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the
> > --remove-orphans flag to clean it up. Starting fraud_detection_generator_1 ... done Attaching to
> > fraud_detection_generator_1 generator_1  | Traceback (most recent call
> > last): generator_1  |   File "app.py", line 28, in 
> > generator_1  |     producer.send(TRANSACTIONS_TOPIC,
> > value=transaction) generator_1  |   File
> > "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line
> > 583, in send generator_1  |     topic, value) generator_1  |   File
> > "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line
> > 714, in _serialize generator_1  |     return f(data) generator_1  |
> > File "app.py", line 24, in  generator_1  |
> > value_serializer=lambda value: json.dumps(value).encode(), generator_1
> > | NameError: name 'json' is not defined fraud_detection_generator_1
> > exited with code 1

Here is the full code for the Producer App:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import json

from kafka import KafkaProducer
from transactions import create_random_transaction

TRANSACTIONS_TOPIC = os.environ.get('TRANSACTIONS_TOPIC')
KAFKA_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('KAFKA_BROKER_URL')
TRANSACTIONS_PER_SECOND = float(os.environ.get('TRANSACTIONS_PER_SECOND'))
SLEEP_TIME = 1 / TRANSACTIONS_PER_SECOND


if __name__ == '__main__':
    producer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_BROKER_URL,
        # Encode all values as JSON
        value_serializer=lambda value: json.dumps(value).encode(),
    )
    while True:
        transaction: dict = create_random_transaction()
        producer.send(TRANSACTIONS_TOPIC, value=transaction)
        print(transaction)  # DEBUG
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

If I run a command json in the terminal it runs fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: looks like you are missing `json` module, try to install it using `pip`

Comment: Hi, json module is native to python. Also, if I open python in the command line and import json, it works fine

Comment: I changed the package from json to rjson - and am still getting the same error

Comment: rjson definitely needs installed... While this code should work, have you tried upgrading Python